Caculating total debt from the SEC edgar API company facts us-gaap data
Is it possible to use a standardized formula for computing the "total debt" using data from the SEC Edgar company facts API?
The problem is all of the fields returned are different for every company.
Here are the fields for one company containing the word Debt for example:
AdjustmentsToAdditionalPaidInCapitalEquityComponentOfConvertibleDebt
AmortizationOfDebtDiscountPremium
DebtInstrumentCarryingAmount
DebtInstrumentFaceAmount
DebtInstrumentInterestRateDuringPeriod
DebtInstrumentInterestRateStatedPercentage
DebtInstrumentUnamortizedDiscount
GainsLossesOnExtinguishmentOfDebt
ProceedsFromIssuanceOfLongTermDebt
AvailableForSaleDebtSecuritiesAccumulatedGrossUnrealizedGainBeforeTax
AvailableForSaleDebtSecuritiesAccumulatedGrossUnrealizedLossBeforeTax
AvailableForSaleDebtSecuritiesAmortizedCostBasis
AvailableForSaleSecuritiesDebtSecurities
DebtSecuritiesHeldToMaturityFairValueCurrent
DebtSecuritiesHeldToMaturityFairValueNoncurrent
ProceedsFromSaleOfAvailableForSaleSecuritiesDebt
AvailableForSaleSecuritiesDebtSecuritiesCurrent
DebtSecuritiesAvailableForSaleAmortizedCostCurrent
DebtIssuanceCostsIncurredDuringNoncashOrPartialNoncashTransaction
PaymentsOfDebtIssuanceCosts

While here are the fields for a different company:

DebtInstrumentCarryingAmount
DebtInstrumentUnamortizedDiscount
DebtIssuanceCosts
DebtRelatedCommitmentFeesAndDebtIssuanceCosts
InterestExpenseDebt
LongTermDebt
LongTermDebtFairValue
LongTermDebtMaturitiesRepaymentsOfPrincipalAfterYearFive
LongTermDebtMaturitiesRepaymentsOfPrincipalInNextTwelveMonths
LongTermDebtMaturitiesRepaymentsOfPrincipalInYearFive
LongTermDebtMaturitiesRepaymentsOfPrincipalInYearFour
LongTermDebtMaturitiesRepaymentsOfPrincipalInYearThree
LongTermDebtMaturitiesRepaymentsOfPrincipalInYearTwo
LongTermDebtMaturitiesRepaymentsOfPrincipalRemainderOfFiscalYear
PaymentsOfDebtIssuanceCosts
ProceedsFromIssuanceOfLongTermDebt
ProceedsFromRepaymentsOfShortTermDebt
ProceedsFromShortTermDebt
RepaymentsOfLongTermDebt
RepaymentsOfShortTermDebt
SecuredDebt
ShortTermDebtWeightedAverageInterestRate
ShorttermDebtFairValue

The second example looks straight forward, LongTermDebt + ShorttermDebtFairValue however the first example less so and these are just two examples of many. Every company will have different fields populated
